# DataTables Ajax data not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Refer to my codes below, it's working when `innerData` is used but when `outerData` is used it's not working and telling me:

> Requested unknown parameter 'badge' for row 0

My `innerData` and `outerData` looks the same, only the values are different.

Appreciate it if anyone can point me to the right direction.

EDIT:Gyrocode.com from comment below suggested `JSON.parse(outerData)` and it works like a charm.

```
$("#ButtonSearch").click(function(){
    try {
        companyCode = '<%=Session["comp_code"].ToString()%>';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "MtForm.aspx/helloWorld",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{companyCode:" + JSON.stringify(companyCode) + "}",
            success: function(outerData){
                var innerData = [{"badge":"11111111","name":"John Doe","ext":"2222","dept_name":"3333"},{"badge":"44444444","name":"Jane Doe","ext":"5555","dept_name":"6666"}];

                $('#demo').html( '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"><thead><tr><th>Badge</th><th>Name</th><th>Ext.</th><th>Dept.</th></tr></thead></table>' );

                $('#example').dataTable({
                    "data": innerData,
                    "columns": [
                        { "data": 'badge' },
                        { "data": 'name' },
                        { "data": 'ext' },
                        { "data": 'dept_name' }
                    ]
                });                        
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(status);
                console.log(error);
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        alert('Javascript error: ' + err.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: if you `console.log(outerData)`, can you tell us what the console shows.

Comment: It will look exactly like "innerData", only the value is different.

Comment: LOG: [{"badge":"XXXXXXXXX","name":"XXXXXXXX","ext":"","dept_name":"MIS"}]

Comment: Remove `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"`. Datatable does not support it

Comment: Try  `"data": JSON.parse(outerData),`.

Answer (score 0):

DataTables have the ability to read data from virtually any JSON data source that can be obtained by Ajax. This can be done, in its most simple form, by setting the `ajax` option. See the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

In your case, it should be something like:

```
   var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "MtForm.aspx/helloWorld",
        "data": function (d) {
            return JSON.stringify(
                $.extend( {}, d, {
                    "companyCode ": '<%=Session["comp_code"].ToString()%>'
                })
            )
        },
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
    },
    deferLoading: true,
    "columns": [
        { "data": 'badge' },
        { "data": 'name' },
        { "data": 'ext' },
        { "data": 'dept_name' }
    ]
});  
// execute request when all necessary data were loaded
table.draw();
```